# My Poland visa is expired. I want to go back to my home country India

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, india, poland

I have been studying in Poland since 2015 and now my studies are about to finish so I want to go back to my home country (India). But my TRC was expired by 1st of September and I already applied for the extension of my TRC but still not yet given my fingerprints. So I am sure that it will take more than 3 months for the extension but I don't want to wait that much time here I just want to go back to India as soon as I get the degree.

So will there be any problem while I am going back to India without a valid Poland visa (but I have valid Indian Passport)?

If there is any problem then How to sort out?

Comment: Overstaying a Shengen visa results in a fine and/or a (tempoary) ban from the Shengen zone, and yes they will check when you fly out of the country. Looking [here](http://www.euro-dollar-currency.com/overstaying_schengen_visa.htm) it sounds like it's often 500-700 EUR, and you may or may not be allowed to return for several years.

Comment: Thank you for the information. And overstay is not my intention. I am here just because of my degree as soon as I get it I will leave. My worry is I don't  want to get any ban or stamp on my name because I may visit another country in future. And I am not ready to pay also because I already Applied for extension Can't it be helpful.

Comment: It sounds as if the OP has been in Poland on a long-term visa. Does anyone know if his timely application for an extension thereof means that he has not, in fact, overstayed for purposes of fine/ban?

Comment: @Mako212: in some countries I know, students visa are automatically/easily transformed into tourist visa or job-seeker visa.  Also, the treatment of the demand for the extension of visa can be quite long and some countries (ex: France) grants you a certificate of application for extension and you are not illegally overstaying. Of course, this is all from memory and my meager experience, so the OP should check carefully the local laws. Just to say that the OP is not necessarily overstaying and "finable".

Comment: When did you apply for prolongation of your residence permit? Didn't you get any document confirming it?

Comment: I applied on 1st of September. I will get the stamp confirming that My visa extension is under process when I give my fingerprints but till now they did not send me a letter to give fingerprints. so right now I just have confirmation on one of my application forms that I submitted required forms. Can i show that and leave this country?

Answer (score 1):

You can travel to India with your valid Indian passport at any time. If you want to return to Poland later you can apply for regular travel visa.

Comment: Could there be problems at the exit check?  Could the traveler be fined or banned from the Schengen area?  If so, would it be helpful to document the pending TRC extension?

Comment: won't they check my visa status while leaving EU zone? My main concern is I heard they will issue a stamp on my passport about overstay or Ban me for some time is it true?

Comment: The second sentence of this answer is so wishful thinking!