# My Poland visa is expired. Although my stay in Poland is legal as I have applied to TRC, I want to go back to my home country India

Tags: visas

I am also in the same situation as my visa has expired but I have a stamp on my passport saying I applied for the TRC. Now I want to travel back to India permanently. You can travel back to India with an expired visa from Poland. Can you please share your experience? I heard that we should exit Europe from Poland itself, meaning fly outside the EU and then take a connecting flight to India in such situation.

Would please somebody share some info here?

Comment: Question to which this is connected: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102459/my-poland-visa-is-expired-i-want-to-go-back-to-my-home-country-india

Answer (score 2):

> You can travel back to India with an expired visa from Poland.

It's your passport that permits travel to India; the expired visa does not have a bearing on your departure from Poland (only whether application for TRC indicates you have not overstayed).

> I heard that we should exit Europe from Poland itself, meaning fly outside the EU and then take a connecting flight to India in such situation.

While you initiate your journey from within the EU, Poland, any connecting flight would have to be through a country for which you don't need a visa to transit, or for which you obtain a visa (either in advance or, if eligible, on arrival).